# Subpartitioning elements of a list based on some h[ri] == h[rj] test

Tags: list-manipulation

If we have a list of elements:

```
list = {r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12};
```

I'd like to further partition the elements into sets where, for some function `h` it will always be the case that `h[ri] == h[rj]` (`i` and `j` being any pair of indices for elements in the set).  I can also promise that it will always be that case `h[ri] != h[rj]` if `ri` and `rj` are from two distinct such subpartitionings.

For example, we could write:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
```

And we could ask for a partitioning of the elements based on `h := Mod[#, 3] &`, which would then give the subpartitioning:

```
list = {{3, 6, 9, 12}, {1, 4, 7, 10}, {2, 5, 8, 11}};
```

Is there a neat way to do this for an arbitrary test function in Mathematica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GatherBy[ list, Mod[#, 3] &]
```

> ```
> {{1, 4, 7, 10}, {2, 5, 8, 11}, {3, 6, 9, 12}}
> ```

Comment: Or `Gather[list, Mod[#1, 3] == Mod[#2, 3] &]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Version 10 built-in `GroupBy`. It can be invoked in two ways:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

Values@GroupBy[list,Mod[#,3]&]
(* {{1, 4, 7, 10}, {2, 5, 8, 11}, {3, 6, 9, 12}} *)

Values@GroupBy[Mod[#,3]&]@list
(* {{1, 4, 7, 10}, {2, 5, 8, 11}, {3, 6, 9, 12}} *)
```